# Citation in a citation

Tags: citing, multiple-citations

Because I am not able to understand French, I have to use a "secondary citation" (so a citation in a citation). Unfortunately I am not sure if this is really the English term for it. In my mother tongue (German) we call this "Sekundärzitat".

I want to get the following output: "This follows from [10, cited after [3, p.~44]."

I tried to do it as follows: "This follows from \cite[cited after \cite[p.~23]{Z}]{F}.", but this did not work. LaTeX says that there is a mistake.

Do you have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Remember that LaTeX does not know about `matching []` when handling optional arguments in `[]`, so try `\cite[zitiert nach {\cite[S. 23]{Z}}]{F}`. In your example the optional argument to the outer `\cite`  is `zitiert nach \cite[S. 23` which then is wrong when it tries to use it.

Comment: Thanks, this works :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whenever LaTeX parses an argument in `[]`'s, it does so ad hoc, it does not know about matching `[]`.

So in the processing of `\cite[cited after \cite[p.~23]{Z}]{F}`, the outer `\cite` sees

- `cited after \cite[p.~23` as its optional argumnent
- `{Z}` as its main argument
- `]{F}` is left over.

This then goes wrong when the outer `\cite` trys to typeset its optional argument as cited after `\cite[p.~23` is incomplete.

With these kinds of issues the solution is to hide the inner set of `[]`'s, aka use

```
\cite[zitiert nach {\cite[S.~23]{Z}}]{F}
```

then the "argument parser" does not see the inner set of `[]`'s and does not get confused.